# while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) - How to foreach $row?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, row

I am working on a simple order system.

the peice of code I am stuck on is the following:

```
if (isset($_GET['cart']))
{
$cart = array();
$total = 0;
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $id)
{
    foreach ($items as $product)
    {
        if ($product['id'] == $id)
        {
            $cart[] = $product;
            $total += $product['price'];
            break;
        }
    }
}

include 'cart.html.php';
exit();
}
```

This is the code is build on a preset array. I am working with a table with a few columns in mysql.

I have decided on the following:

```
if (isset($_GET['cart']))
{
$cart = array();
$total = 0;
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $id)
{
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($productsSql)) {
    foreach ($row as $product)
    {
        if ($product['id'] == $id)
        {
            $cart[] = $product;
            $total += $product['price'];
            break;
        }
    }
}
    include 'cart.html.php';
exit();
}}
```

To display this "cart" I have decided on this:

```
foreach ($cart as $item) {
        $pageContent .= '
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$item['desc'].'</td>
                    <td>
                        R'.number_format($item['price'], 2).'
                    </td>
                </tr>
';

    }
```

All this seems to do is produce my cart in a fashion where when viewed it displays a list of only the items' id, e.g. where the description and price are supposed to be, I only get the items id in both fields... I also get a total price of 0.

Can anyone spot where I am going wrong here?

Or atleast try to give me some input so that I get going in the right direction!

Thanks!!

```
$productsQuery = 'SELECT `id`, `refCode`, `desc`, `pack`, `measure`, `quantity`, `deptCode`, `taxable`, `price1`, `price2`, `crdCode`, `cost1`, `cost2` FROM `products` ORDER BY `desc` ';
$productsSql = mysql_query($productsQuery) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($productsSql) == 0) {
die('No results.');
} else {
$orderContent = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($productsSql)) {
$prId = $row['id'];
$prRefCode = $row['refCode'];
$prDesc = $row['desc'];
$prPack = $row['pack'];
$prMeasure = $row['measure'];
$prQuantity = $row['quantity'];
$prDeptCode = $row['deptCode'];
$prTaxable = $row['taxable'];
$prPrice1 = $row['price1'];
$prPrice2 = $row['price2'];
$prCrdCode = $row['crdCode'];
$prCost1 = $row['cost1'];
$prCost2 = $row['cost2'];
$orderContent .= '
    <tr>
        <td>'.$prId.'</td>
        <td>'.$prDesc.'</td>
        <td>'.$prPack.'x'.$prSize.' '.$prMeasure.'</td>
        <td>R'.$prPrice1.'</td>
        <td>
            <form action="" method="post">
                <div>
                    <input type="text" size="3" name="quantity" /> 
                </div>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form action="" method="post">
                <div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$prId.'" />
                    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Order" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </td>           
   </tr>
';
}}
```

Comment: @yokoloko see edit in my post

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let's say that each of the rows in your database looks like this...

```
[product_id][product_name][product_description][product_price]
```

When you assign your query return to a variable passed through `mysql_fetch_assoc()` using a while loop, each pass will isolate a whole row. Of which you can piece apart manually by array key reference (`$array['product_id']`) or by using a foreach loop. I think the problem you're having is that you are mixing this up. Keeping the above example table layout in mind, you could do something like the following:

```
while ($tableRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { // Loops 3 times if there are 3 returned rows... etc

    foreach ($tableRow as $key => $value) { // Loops 4 times because there are 4 columns
        echo $value;
        echo $tableRow[$key]; // Same output as previous line
    }
    echo $tableRow['product_id']; // Echos 3 times each row's product_id value
}
```

Look at this line in your code: `if ($product['id'] == $id) { }`

I think you probably mean `if ($row['id'] == $id) { }` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Your middle code block makes no sense. You loop over session variables, and run a query each time... but it's the SAME query, and using an undefined variable to boot. Looping over a result row doesn't make much sense, as you'd be looping over the individual fields that your query returns for each row.

e.g. If your products table has just `(id, name, description)` as fields, then `$row` would be an array that looks like:

```
$row = array('id' => xxx, 'name' => yyy, 'description' => zzz);
```

When you `foreach()` on `$row()`, you'd not getting individual products, you'd be getting those fields in the row. $product would be `xxx`, then `yyy`, then `zzz`.

I don't know what your code is trying to accomplish - I'd guess you're trying to retrieve prices for products that a user is adding into their cart, but you're going about it in a very strange and highly inefficient manner.

Comment: Thanks for the input, yes it is strange and confusing for me too. What I am trying to accomplish is have a catalogue of products and their prices. A user can select a product by clicking order on the appropriate line. When viewing the "cart" it will display a list of items that have been ordered, along with a total based on the sum of the price of each item that was added to the cart. On finalization, the order will be sent off via email. I am just brain storming here :)