# How to access multi dimentional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

Hello i am fetching data from database by using mysqli_fetch_assoc() and getting this result

```
Array
(
    [poi_id] => 1
    [created_id] => 1
    [tour_id] => 1
    [poi_title] => Kankariya Lake
    [poi_description] => Kankariya lake is a kankariya lake.
    [poi_category] => Historical
    [poi_base_price] => 10
    [poi_type] => driving
    [poi_address] => Kankaariya lake near maninagar
    [poi_city] => Ahmedabad
    [poi_state] => Gujaray
    [poi_country] => India
    [poi_latitude] => 23.006353
    [poi_longitude] => 72.601181
    [created_by] => Admin
    [status] => 1
    [time] => 2019-03-06 15:14:25
    [distance] => 7.981589182296636
)
Array
(
    [poi_id] => 2
    [created_id] => 1
    [tour_id] => 2
    [poi_title] => Kankariya Lake
    [poi_description] => Kankariya lake is a kankariya lake.
    [poi_category] => Historical
    [poi_base_price] => 10
    [poi_type] => driving
    [poi_address] => Kankaariya lake near maninagar
    [poi_city] => Ahmedabad
    [poi_state] => Gujaray
    [poi_country] => India
    [poi_latitude] => 23.006353
    [poi_longitude] => 72.601181
    [created_by] => Admin
    [status] => 1
    [time] => 2019-03-07 16:51:11
    [distance] => 7.981589182296636
)
Array
(
    [poi_id] => 3
    [created_id] => 1
    [tour_id] => 2
    [poi_title] => Kankariya Lake
    [poi_description] => Kankariya lake is a kankariya lake.
    [poi_category] => Historical
    [poi_base_price] => 10
    [poi_type] => driving
    [poi_address] => Kankaariya lake near maninagar
    [poi_city] => Ahmedabad
    [poi_state] => Gujaray
    [poi_country] => India
    [poi_latitude] => 23.006353
    [poi_longitude] => 72.601181
    [created_by] => Admin
    [status] => 1
    [time] => 2019-03-07 17:06:44
    [distance] => 7.981589182296636
)
```

So now i want to access perticular array element in for loop so how i can access that elements
i want to compare latitude and longitude with all other lat long of array
**my updated code**

```
while ($poi_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry_res)) 
{
    $poi_id=$poi_array['poi_id'];
    $new[]=$poi_array;
    //print_r($new);
    $lat1=$poi_array['poi_latitude'];
    $lon1=$poi_array['poi_longitude'];  
    //echo $new['poi_longitude'][1];

    $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
    $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
    $dist = acos($dist);
    $dist = rad2deg($dist);
    $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    $km= $miles * 1.609344;
    $meter=$km*1000;
    //echo round($meter);
    if($meter>1000)
    {                   
        $response2['success'] = true;
        $response2['message'] = "Pointof Interest list successfully fetched";
    }
    $fetch_media="SELECT * FROM poito_poi_media WHERE poi_id='".$poi_id."'";
    $media_qry_res = mysqli_query($con,$fetch_media);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($media_qry_res) > 0) 
    {
        while ($media_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($media_qry_res)) 
        {
            $response4['media_id'] = $media_array['media_id'];
            $response4['image'] = $media_array['poi_image'];
            $response4['video'] = $media_array['poi_video'];
            $response4['ar'] = $media_array['poi_ar'];
            $response5[]=$response4;
            $response6['media_array']=$response5;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $response6['media_array']=null;
    }
    $response['poi_id'] = $poi_array['poi_id'];
    $response['poi_title'] = $poi_array['poi_title'];
    $response['poi_description'] = $poi_array['poi_description'];
    $response['poi_category'] = $poi_array['poi_category'];
    $response['poi_base_price'] = $poi_array['poi_base_price'];
    $response['poi_type'] = $poi_array['poi_type'];
    $response['poi_address'] = $poi_array['poi_address'];
    $response['poi_city'] = $poi_array['poi_city'];
    $response['poi_state'] = $poi_array['poi_state'];
    $response['poi_country'] = $poi_array['poi_country'];
    $response['poi_latitude'] = $poi_array['poi_latitude'];
    $response['poi_longitude'] = $poi_array['poi_longitude'];
    unset($response5);
    $response['media_array'] = $response6['media_array'];

    $response3[]=$response;
    $response2['data']=$response3;
}
```

if Distance of other element of array within 1000meter then only give response of just one element no need to add another data in array

means this are placeinfo too remove same place if one place come multiple time  then we have to show only one place

Comment: Use `foreach` loop

Comment: You already have a loop, you just need to fetch the elements from the loop in that loop.

Comment: How exactly do you get the given result? Can you share the existing code and mark the points where you are stuck?

Comment: it is multi dimentional 
so how can i access poi_latitude and poi_longitude in loop?
@AnkurTiwari

Comment: @NicoHaase
the above is my array which name is 
$poi_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry_res);
now i want to compare two cordinate lat long la tlong to check which are within 200meter

Comment: Put a loop on the result that you are getting from `mysqli_fetch_assoc` and you can directly access the value.

Comment: @AnkurTiwari please write code here  or in answer

Comment: code to print every poi_lat poi_long @AnkurTiwari

Comment: I would suggest trying to figure it out yourself first with the hints given above and post your efforts here if you can't make it work. SO is not a coding service ;)

Comment: @PHPDeveloper Check this link first answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962771/whilerow-mysql-fetch-assocresult-how-to-foreach-row

Comment: i am trying it from last two days and now i am stucked!

Comment: @PHPDeveloper You can try the same with your code

Comment: @AnkurTiwari trying with your link

Comment: @AnkurTiwari iam already getting in while loop 
but in while loop i a want another loop

Comment: @PHPDeveloper Can you share your code here

Comment: while ($poi_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry_res)) {
echo $poi_array['poi_latitude'];
} This is ok @AnkurTiwari

Comment: now in this loop i want to compare rest of lat long
suppose 1st call  of while loop i want to put condition and want to compare  the rest of lat long from array@AnkurTiwari

Comment: You're probably better off storing all the values from SQL in a separate array, and work on that array. See my answer below.

Comment: From what I understand, you cannot do this unless you first store _all_ the values in an array, and _then_ run a loop over them. What the loop needs to do is better if you ask in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

var_dump($rows);
//You can remove this
//it's just so that you can see the contents of the $row array
```

You will then be able to traverse the `$rows` array to find whatever values you want. You can put `$rows` in a `foreach()` loop like so:

```
foreach($rows as $row){
    //$row['poi_latitude']
    //$row['poi_longitude']
}
```

Comment: How is this helping to access 2 fields in an array?

Comment: I have widened the answer to help OP further.